# Modify regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to get first pair of numbers from "**09**_135624.jpg"

My code now:

```
import re

string = "09_135624.jpg"
pattern = r"(?P<pair>(.*))_135624.jpg"
match = re.findall(pattern, string)

print match
```

Output:

```
[('09', '09')]
```

Why I have tuple in output?

Can you help me modify my code to get this:

```
['09']
```

Or:

```
'09'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns differently according to the number of capturing group in the pattern:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?P<pair>.*)_135624\.jpg", "09_135624.jpg")
['09']
```

According to the documentation:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group.** Empty matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of another match.

---

Alternative using `re.search`:

```
>>> re.search(r"(?P<pair>.*)_135624\.jpg", "09_135624.jpg")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000025D0D50>
>>> re.search(r"(?P<pair>.*)_135624\.jpg", "09_135624.jpg").group('pair')
'09'
>>> re.search(r"(?P<pair>.*)_135624\.jpg", "09_135624.jpg").group(1)
'09'
```

**UPDATE**

To match `.` literally, you need to escape it: `\.`.

Comment: Thank you. My pattern now is "(?P<pair>([0-9][0-9])):?(.*).jpg", and i used re.search for taking needed group. Vks helped me with demo, you helped with answer about re.search, so i dont know what answer i can accept...

Comment: @ValeriyG, You can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, Thank you for pointing that. updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?P<pair>(?:.*))_135624.jpg
```

Try this. You are getting two results because you are capturing them twice. I have modified it to capture only once:

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/62